# Bash script, need help for loop

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

Currently I'm using this script to block China's IP address:

```
# Create the ipset list
ipset -N china hash:net

# remove any old list that might exist from previous runs of this script
rm cn.zone

# Pull the latest IP set for China
wget -P . http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone

# Add each IP address from the downloaded list into the ipset 'china'
for i in $(cat ./cn.zone ); do ipset -A china $i; done

# Restore iptables
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

**This works fine but how can I use it with multiple countries?**

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ipset -N blockall hash:net
rm blockall.zone

for i in $(wget -P . http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone);
do ipset -A blockall $i; done

/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Agnul's answer, I tried this:

```
rm blockall.zone
# pull files for each country
wget -P . http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone

# for each country file
for c in *.zone; do

  #for each line in country
  while read i; do
    ipset -A blockall $i;
  done <"$c"

done
```

Then I `chmod` my script

`chmod +x /etc/block-blockall.sh`

However it doesn't create the file `blockall.zone` or singular file `*.zone` as it should.

Comment: It doesn't work because this `{cn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}` it's wrong...what's the right method of array in bash? Apologies in advance for the simplicity of this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the first script, china's one, is doing what you expect, try this one to handle several countries:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTRIES="cn in iq af ir ae sg hk kw kg"

ipset -N blockall hash:net

for country in $COUNTRIES; do
  wget -O - http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/$country.zone 2>/dev/null | while read ip; do
    ipset -A blockall $ip; 
  done
done


/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

note temporary file is not need nor used.

If, for any reason, the temporary file is need, use:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTRIES="cn in iq af ir ae sg hk kw kg" 
ZONEFILE=blockall.zone

rm -f $ZONEFILE

ipset -N blockall hash:net

for country in $COUNTRIES; do
  wget -O - http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/$country.zone 2>/dev/null >> $ZONEFILE
done

while read ip; do
  ipset -A blockall $ip; 
done < $ZONEFILE

/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
# pull files for each country
wget -P . http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone

# for each country file
for c in *.zone; do

  #for each line in country
  while read i; do
    ipset -A blockall $i;
  done <"$c"

done
```

should work.

Comment: I tried but same error `--2016-05-27 10:33:18--  http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/%7Bcn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg%7D.zone
Resolving www.ipdeny.com (www.ipdeny.com)... 192.xxx.xxx.22
Connecting to www.ipdeny.com (www.ipdeny.com)|192.xxx.xxx.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-27 10:33:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: `for i in $(cat ...)` is an antipattern. Use a `while`-`read` loop instead. Also, it should be `"$c"` alone, and not `$c.zone`, since the expansion `$c` will have the trailing `.zone`.

Comment: yeah I didn't really try that ;-) my bad.

Comment: Sorry but I get again the same error...`wget` is not working in this way

Comment: wget is receiving 404 error codes from the server, and it's not downloading the files. Are you sure you're using actual curly braces on the command line and not the `%7B` `%7D` url-encoded stuff above?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, but I forgot to remove this line `ipset -N blockall hash:net` . However the script doesn't create the new file `blockall.zone`

Comment: www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,in,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone is not valid URL

Comment: If the shell used is `bash` as the tags and title claim, then [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) generates a list of potentially valid URLs: `www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone
www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/in.zone` …
`www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/kw.zone
www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/kg.zone`.  If the shell in use is not Bash (e.g. `/bin/sh`), then the expansion may not occur (`/bin/sh` might not be Bash, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: See at first comment a proof that shell (unknown one) is not doing brace expansion.